# Pin docker-ce version in ansible playbook

Tags: ansible, docker-ce

I'm trying to install a docker-ce specific version but after running the playbook it keeps instaling the latest.

Let me know what I'm doing wrong :)

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - name: Install dep
    apt:
     name:
       - apt-transport-https
       - ca-certificates
       - curl
       - software-properties-common
       - python3-setuptools
     state: latest
     update_cache: true

  - name: Install python dep
    become: true
    apt:
     update_cache: yes
     state: latest
     name: python3-pip

  - name: Install 'Docker SDK for Python'
    pip:
     name:
       - docker
       - docker-compose

  - name: Install Docker Key
    become: true
    apt_key:
      url: 'https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg'
      state: present

  - name: Add docker repo
    become: true
    apt_repository:
      repo: 'deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal stable'
      state: present
      filename: docker-ce

  - name: Install docker-ce
    become: true
    apt:
      name: docker-ce=5:24.0.2-1~ubuntu.20.04~focal
      state: present
```

After checking the docker version I get 24.0.6 instead of 24.0.2

Comment: Could it be that it was installed prior to your playbook? If so, you might need to set the parameter [`allow_downgrade`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/apt_module.html#parameter-allow_downgrade) to `true`.